# if loop won't take my if statement - why?

Tags: python

What I'm trying to have happen here is, I want my code to give score1 100 points if there is 1 one in my list, 200 points if there are 2. 300 points if there are 3, and on some rare occasions if there are 4 ones, add 1000 points. But I keep running into issues one of them being that I'll get a number that isn't even a one and it will add it to my score1, why is this happening? For example, this is one of the errors https://gyazo.com/c9b260c7a3306934faff074ab19efa68

```
from random import randint
score1 = 0
def dices():
    score1 = 0
    a = 0
    score_total1 = 0
    score_total2 = 0
    dice1 = randint(1, 6)
    dice2 = randint(1, 6)
    dice3 = randint(1, 6)
    dice4 = randint(1, 6)
    dice5 = randint(1, 6)
    dice6 = randint(1, 6)
    rolled_dice = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6]
    for number in rolled_dice:
        if number == 1:
            score_total1 += number
            if score_total1 == 1:
                score1 += 100
            elif score_total1 == 2:
                score1 += 200
            elif score_total1 == 3:
                score1 += 300
            elif score_total1 == 4:
                score1 += 1000
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you can simplify your `rolled_dice` by using `[random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(6)]` or something similar

Comment: What game is this for? It almost seems similar to Zilch.

Comment: It's for a game called farkle

Comment: I think farkle and zilch are the same game. But with slightly different rules, maybe? I've seen lots of variations on rules for this game.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is not what you think it is. What's happening is that when your code sees the first `1` in the score list, it adds `100` to the score. Then it sees another `1` and adds 200 to the score. So you end up with a score of 300. It's not that your code thinks there's 3 `1`'s in the list. I don't think looping over the list is necessary in this case, since `list` has a built-in `count` function.

Try this:

```
rolled_dice = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6]
one_count = rolled_dice.count(1)
return [0, 100, 200, 300, 1000][one_count]
```

Though you should probably have a plan for what happens if you roll more than 4 `1`s. But I'll leave that part up to you.

Comment: This was really helpful thank you, I would 1+ you but I don't have a high enough rep yet (everyone always downvoting me) I would have never thought of a cool method like that thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in calculating the number of 1's in the list, there is an easier way using list comprehensions:

```
n_ones = sum([num == 1 for num in rolled_dice])
```

Then, you can decide how to perform the score based on the number of ones. Thus, you could imagine restructuring your code in this way instead of looping through rolled_dice.

As for getting situations where the score is incremented when there's no 1, it doesn't look like this happens. If we modify your code to include a return statement

```
def dices():
score1 = 0
a = 0
score_total1 = 0
score_total2 = 0
dice1 = randint(1, 6)
dice2 = randint(1, 6)
dice3 = randint(1, 6)
dice4 = randint(1, 6)
dice5 = randint(1, 6)
dice6 = randint(1, 6)
rolled_dice = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6]
for number in rolled_dice:
    if number == 1:
        score_total1 += number
        if score_total1 == 1:
            score1 += 100
        elif score_total1 == 2:
            score1 += 200
        elif score_total1 == 3:
            score1 += 300
        elif score_total1 == 4:
            score1 += 1000

return rolled_dice, score1
```

Then, the following code never prints anything

```
for i in range(1000):
    rolled_dice, score1 = dices()

    # Check if the score is nonzero when there is a 1 in rolled_dice
    if not (1 in rolled_dice) and score != 0:
        print(rolled_dice, score1)
```

Indicating that the described situation never happens.